# Load the json data to Gridview according to the Textview click

Tags: android, json

I'm  getting a `responseJson` and I'm trying to exact data to load in my grid view. I have 2 textviews in my screen and once I press 1 textview then items which belongs to `SubCategoryID =1` should load. When the textview 2 is pressed then the items belongs to `SubCategoryID = 2` should load.

I have given the code below,

```
@Override
    public void onTaskCompleted(JSONArray responseJson) {

    try {
        final List<String> descriptions = new ArrayList<String>();
        final List<String> imageUrls = new ArrayList<String>();

        for (int i = 0; i < responseJson.length(); ++i) {
            final JSONObject object = responseJson.getJSONObject(i);

            mQuickReturnViewTop
            .setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    try {
                        if ((object.getString("MainCategoryID"))
                                .equals("1")
                                && (object
                                        .getString("SubCategoryID"))
                                        .equals("1")) {
                            Log.i("ImageURL ",
                                    object.getString("ImageURL"));
                            imageUrls.add(object
                                    .getString("ImageURL"));
                            Log.i("Description ",
                                    object.getString("Description"));
                            descriptions.add(object
                                    .getString("Description"));

                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    CustomGridPizza adapter = new CustomGridPizza(
                            getActivity(), descriptions, imageUrls);
                    grid.setAdapter(adapter);

                }

            });

            mQuickReturnViewIta
            .setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    try {
                        if ((object.getString("MainCategoryID"))
                                .equals("1")
                                && (object
                                        .getString("SubCategoryID"))
                                        .equals("2")) {
                            Log.i("ImageURL ",
                                    object.getString("ImageURL"));
                            imageUrls.add(object
                                    .getString("ImageURL"));
                            Log.i("Description ",
                                    object.getString("Description"));
                            descriptions.add(object
                                    .getString("Description"));
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    CustomGridPizza adapter = new CustomGridPizza(
                            getActivity(), descriptions, imageUrls);
                    grid.setAdapter(adapter);

                }

            });
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

When using this code, it loads only 1 item and when keep pressing the text view then it adds the same item one by one.

I need help to load the items to grid at once. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For every JSON object you are creating a new OnClickListener and overwriting the last one with the call to setOnClickListener, so basically you are always adding the last JSON object.
You need to create/set the OnClickListener and the adapter **outside** of the for loop.

```
try {
        final List<String> descriptions1 = new ArrayList<String>();
        final List<String> imageUrls1 = new ArrayList<String>();

        final List<String> descriptions2 = new ArrayList<String>();
        final List<String> imageUrls2 = new ArrayList<String>();

        for (int i = 0; i < responseJson.length(); ++i) {
            final JSONObject object = responseJson.getJSONObject(i);

            try {
                if ((object.getString("MainCategoryID"))
                        .equals("1")
                        && (object
                        .getString("SubCategoryID"))
                        .equals("1")) {
                    Log.i("ImageURL ",
                            object.getString("ImageURL"));
                    imageUrls1.add(object
                            .getString("ImageURL"));
                    Log.i("Description ",
                            object.getString("Description"));
                    descriptions1.add(object
                            .getString("Description"));

                }else if ((object.getString("MainCategoryID"))
                        .equals("1")
                        && (object
                        .getString("SubCategoryID"))
                        .equals("2")) {
                    Log.i("ImageURL ",
                            object.getString("ImageURL"));
                    imageUrls2.add(object
                            .getString("ImageURL"));
                    Log.i("Description ",
                            object.getString("Description"));
                    descriptions2.add(object
                            .getString("Description"));
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            mQuickReturnViewTop
                    .setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {



                            CustomGridPizza adapter = new CustomGridPizza(
                                    getActivity(), descriptions1, imageUrls1);
                            grid.setAdapter(adapter);

                        }

                    });

            mQuickReturnViewIta
                    .setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {

                            CustomGridPizza adapter = new CustomGridPizza(
                                    getActivity(), descriptions2, imageUrls2);
                            grid.setAdapter(adapter);

                        }

                    });
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, then how can I match and load the SubCategoryID =1 to respective text view? When I create the adapter outside for loop then all the items (items belongs to SubCategoryID 1 and 2) load in the grid.

Comment: You could create two sets of lists or even two adapters (for each subcategory), and when clicking their respective buttons to set the correct adapter on the grid

Comment: Do u mind helping me with coding level please. I can't set 2 adapters inside respective click event

Comment: I have edited my answer with a code example. This is just to give you an idea, you could further improve on it.

Comment: thanks your idea was very useful for me. In here no need to use else if, I used if in all the places. If u can change that then I can vote for ur answer :)